# Return ArrayList Object Dynamically in Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, arraylist

I need help on Java reflection. Based on the attached code, I am not sure how the return an ArrayList of a class object dynamically in buildPersonDynamically method. The logic is something like in buildPerson method. Please refer to MyMain.java.

```
package reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import reflection.builder.PersonBuilder;
import reflection.one.two.three.Person;

public class MyMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {                
    buildPerson(3);
    buildPersonDynamically(3);
}   
static void buildPerson(int total) {
    PersonBuilder pb = new PersonBuilder();

    pb.build(3);
    ArrayList<Person> per = pb.getDataSet();
    System.out.println(per.get(1).FirstName);
}   
static void buildPersonDynamically(int total) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = java.lang.Class.forName("reflection.builder.PersonBuilder");
        Object obj = c.newInstance();            

        Class<Integer> partypes = Integer.TYPE;
        Method m1 = c.getMethod("build", partypes);
        m1.invoke(obj, total);

        Method m2 = c.getMethod("getFirstName", partypes);
        Object objStr = m2.invoke(obj, 2);
        System.out.println(objStr.toString()); // success

        Method m3 = c.getMethod("getDataSet");

        // Not sure how to get an ArrayList of Person dataSet dynamically.
        // Example, want to get the FirstName from the m3.

    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}



package reflection.builder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import reflection.one.two.three.Person;

public class PersonBuilder {
private ArrayList<Person> dataSet;

public ArrayList<Person> getDataSet() {
    return dataSet;
}

public ArrayList<Person> build(int numberOfRecords) {
    ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> emailAddress = new ArrayList<String>();

    Person per;

    this.dataSet = new ArrayList<Person>();

    firstName.add("Barrack");
    firstName.add("John");
    firstName.add("Whitney");
    firstName.add("Paris");
    firstName.add("Britney");

    lastName.add("Obama");
    lastName.add("Lennon");
    lastName.add("Houston");
    lastName.add("Hilton");
    lastName.add("Spears");

    age.add(47);
    age.add(60);
    age.add(48);
    age.add(32);
    age.add(25);

    emailAddress.add("barrack.obama@gmail.com");
    emailAddress.add("john.lennon@gmail.com");
    emailAddress.add("whitney.houston@gmail.com");
    emailAddress.add("paris.hilton@gmail.com");
    emailAddress.add("britney.spears@gmail.com");

    if (numberOfRecords >= 5) numberOfRecords = 5;
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
        per = new Person();
        per.FirstName = firstName.get(i);
        per.LastName = lastName.get(i);
        per.Age = age.get(i);
        per.EmailAddress = emailAddress.get(i);

        this.dataSet.add(per);
    }   
    return this.dataSet;
}

public String getFirstName(int a) {
    return this.dataSet.get(a).FirstName;
}
}


package reflection.one.two.three;

public class Person {
public String FirstName;
public String LastName;
public int Age;
public String EmailAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are sure that a `ArrayList` is generated you can just cast it.

```
Method m3 = c.getMethod("getDataSet");
Object resultM3 = m3.invoke(obj);
ArrayList<Person> resultListM3 = (ArrayList<Person>) resultM3;
```

Comment: It should compile fine jdk5 or more, `invoke(obj, obj...)` accepts `varargs`. We don't need to pass `null` explicitly if the method doesnt have any params

Comment: @Nitram It works. But is it possible to cast dynamically? So that I can put the 'Person' in a string.

Comment: A string is not possible. But you can use classes instead of `Person` that super-classes of `Person`. Such as `Object`. And if you need Strings at any point then you can easily use `Object.toString()` for the conversation.

Comment: I use getField("FirstName") to get its string value. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just as a tipp: You may want to change your `Person` class to use private variables with getters and setters in case your project is growing larger. Public writable variables tend to lead to crappy code as the project grows. For example with you want to introduce validation of the values or if you need to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Method m3 = c.getMethod("getDataSet");
ArrayList<Person> per = (ArrayList<Person>) m3.invoke(obj, null);
```

The `null` argument of the `invoke` method indicates that there are no arguments to pass to the method.

Comment: I keep forgetting this `null`.

Comment: you don't need a null in the m3.invoke call.  In fact, this would probably be ambigous and general a compile error, since it doesn't know if null is supposed to be a single Object (varargs syntax) argument or Object[] indicating the arguments as an array.  You'd have to case to (Object[]) null   if you wanted no parameters.  It's best just to leave that off the method call in this case.

Comment: @Matt 1. It does compile. 2. Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29): *If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method is 0, **the supplied args array may be of length 0 or null**.* 3. You are right that skipping the parameter altogether is probably more readable.